# Unhandled Exception: [firebase_database/permission-denied]

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am getting this error only in ios
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_database/permission-denied] Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data

whenever I try to read/write data from Firebase Realtime Database, Code runs fine on android but on IOS it just gives me an error mentioned above.

Rules

```js
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Getting data from firebase code

```
DatabaseReference dbref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('chatRooms');
final rooms = await dbref.get();
```

Comment: There should be no difference in behavior between iOS and Android in this respect. Are you sure the iOS device is using the exact same build of the app, and isn't (for example) communicating with another Firebase project where the rules might be different?

Answer (score 0):

Since code runs fine on Android, the problem may be in your iOS configuration.

Instead of using FirebaseDatabase default instance, you can try to explicity specify database url like this:

```
//DatabaseReference dbref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('chatRooms');
final dbref = FirebaseDatabase(databaseURL: 'YOUR-FIREBASE-DB-URL-HERE').ref('chatRooms');
```

If you don't get any error after this, you were simply missing the DB url so let's fix it:

1. Undo the change
2. From Firebase website, open project settings and download "GoogleService-Info.plist"
3. Open Runner.xcworkspace ({project-folder}\ios)
4. Drag and drop the .plist file under: Runner\Runner
5. Check "Copy item if needed", "Create groups" and "Runner"
6. Click "Finish"

Try rerun your app and everything should be working now!